# External replace function not working

Tags: javascript, replace, str-replace

Why do I have to place the replace function inside the str.replace statement?

This works fine:

```
str = str.replace(/&|<|>|"|'/g, function replacer(match) {
switch (match) {
  case "&":
    return "&amp;";
  case "<":
    return "&lt;";
  case ">":
    return "&gt;";
  case '"':
    return "&quot;";
  case "'":
    return "&apos;";
}
});
```

This does not work, returning "Reference error: match is not defined":

```
str = str.replace(/&|<|>|"|'/g, replacer(match));

function replacer(match) {
switch (match) {
  case "&":
    return "&amp;";
  case "<":
    return "&lt;";
  case ">":
    return "&gt;";
  case '"':
    return "&quot;";
  case "'":
    return "&apos;";
}
}
```

Why am I not able to call replacer() as an external function? Passing arguments is a breeze with other functions, but not in this context - from within the str.replace statement. Just curious, if curiosity is allowed. Besides, it bugs me... Thanks!

(Searched and double searched everywhere for an answer before posting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it like this:

```
str = str.replace(/&|<|>|"|'/g, replacer);
```

Meaning you pass the function, not a function call result.

Answer (score 0):

your callback function should be created before use

```
function replacer(match) {
    switch (match) {
      case "&":...
    }
}
str = str.replace(/&|<|>|"|'/g, replacer(match));
```

Comment: Neat! Thanks! I will keep that in mind. JS has a tendency to look a bit messy if one does not take care to use such  good practices. I appreciate it! Regards